# Concurrency control on Flask

Tags: multithreading, flask, python-multithreading

I have a Flask application I want to apply some granular concurrency control to. My application serves long-running, IO-bound requests. The obvious idea would be to use Gunicorn, however I have some specific requirements that mean I have to implement my own solution.

One such requirement being, I want to have a single-process multi-threaded application, with a thread pool handling the worker threads, and a bounded FIFO queue holding a certain number of waiting requests. Any other incoming requests would get immediately refused with status code `429 Too Many Requests` until there's room in the queue.

My first idea was to create a middleware holding a queue and a thread pool, and putting it in front of my app. Something like:

```py
class ConcurrencyControlMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app, max_threads, q_size):
        self.app = app
        self.executor = MyBoundedThreadPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=max_threads, 
            q_size=q_size,
        )

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        try:
            fut = self.executor.submit(self.app, environ, start_response)
            return fut.result()
        except queue.Full:
            flask.abort(HTTPStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
```

However I don't think this would work, since calling `.result()` would block. Instead, I would like the request to be queued, the request to wait until the request is enqueued and processed, and in the meantime other requests be served.

Am I on the good path? Or should I consider a completely different strategy?

Comment: You could finde an answer here (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flack). It propeses a way to make flask endpoints "async" using celery workers and a message queue, so this is similiar to your approach without the need to implement the middleware yourself. There is also a 3h video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdIIJuPh3SI) where this is explained, the interesting part for you starts at around 2h